# Need help validating if user input is a number

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following code:

```
def say(msg)
  puts "=> #{msg}"
end

def do_math(num1, num2, operation)
  case operation
    when '+'
      num1.to_i + num2.to_i
    when '-'
      num1.to_i - num2.to_i
    when '*'
      num1.to_i * num2.to_i
    when '/'
      num1.to_f / num2.to_f
    end
end

say "Welcome to my calculator!"

run_calculator = 'yes'

while run_calculator == 'yes'
  say "What's the first number?"

  num1 = gets.chomp

  say "What's the second number?"

  num2 = gets.chomp

  say "What would you like to do?"

  say "Enter '+' for Addition, '-' for Subtraction, '*' for Multiplication, or '/' for Division"

  operation = gets.chomp

  if num2.to_f == 0 && operation == '/'
    say "You cannot devide by 0, please enter another value!"
    num2 = gets.chomp
  else
    result = do_math(num1, num2, operation)
  end

  say "#{num1} #{operation} #{num2} = #{result}"

  say "Would you like to do another calculation? Yes / No?"
  run_calculator = gets.chomp

  if run_calculator.downcase == 'no'
    say "Thanks for using my calculator!"
  elsif run_calculator.downcase == 'yes'
    run_calculator = 'yes'
  else
    until run_calculator.downcase == 'yes' || run_calculator.downcase == 'no'
      say "Please enter yes or no!"
      run_calculator = gets.chomp
    end
  end
end
```

I need it to take the `num1` and `num2` variables that the user inputs and validate that they are numbers and return a message if they aren't.

I would like to use a Regex, but I don't know if I should create a method for this or just wrap it in a loop.

Comment: When supplying code, reduce it to the bare minimum needed to replicate the problem. In other words, something like `num1 = gets.chomp` would be sufficient, along with another line showing how you tried to test for a numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Integer`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) method will raise an exception when the given string is not a valid number, whereas [`to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-to_i) will fail silently (which I think is not desired behavior):

```
begin
  num = Integer gets.chomp
rescue ArgumentError
  say "Invalid number!"
end
```

If you want a regex solution, this will also work (although I recommend the method above):

```
num = gets.chomp
unless num =~ /^\d+$/
  say "Invalid number!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You would often see each section written something like this:

```
ERR_MSG = "You must enter a non-negative integer"

def enter_non_negative_integer(instruction, error_msg)
  loop do
    puts instruction
    str = gets.strip
    return str.to_i if str =~ /^\d+$/
    puts error_msg
  end
end

x1 = enter_non_negative_integer("What's the first number?", ERR_MSG)
x2 = enter_non_negative_integer("What's the second number?", ERR_MSG)
```

Here's possible dialog:

```
What's the first number?
: cat
You must enter a non-negative integer
What's the first number?
: 4cat
You must enter a non-negative integer
What's the first number?
:             22
#=> 22
What's the second number?
: 51
#=> 51

x1 #=> 22
x2 #=> 51
```